# A way to do this integral without spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus

Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$. How can one integrate

$$\int_B e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}dx\ dy \ dz\ ?$$

The natural idea is spherical coordinates, but it seems like there is a nicer way to tackle this. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The nicer way is to tackle this using spherical coordinates.

Comment: If that $\frac52$ were not there then there may indeed have been a 'nicer' way to do this... but @user17762 is right. What I was saying was $\int e^{x^2+y^2+z^2}=(\int e^{x^2})^3$

Comment: You could do this with trig subs but I will warn you: A world of hurt awaits.